# How to create the child for existing object with self-referential associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model with self-referential associations:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many    :subtasks, class_name: 'Task', foreign_key: "parent_id"
  belongs_to  :parent, class_name: 'Task'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subtasks, allow_destroy: true
  belongs_to  :user
  belongs_to  :project
end
```

The meaning is:

- I create tasks
- To some of the tasks i wanna add some subtasks
- When I'm going to the task_path - /tasks/:id, action 'tasks#show' - i see the attributes of the task, but below i want to have an opportunity to add a subtasks.

And some questions in addition:

1. Is it good way to use one model for Tasks and Subtasks?
2. Do i need to create second controller?

Thank you and sorry for my English.

UPD1:
TasksController

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

  before_action :find_task, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @tasks = Task.where("parent_id IS ?", nil)
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @task = Task.new
    @task.subtasks.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @task = Task.create(task_params)
    if @task.errors.empty?
      redirect_to @task
    else
      render  'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @task.update_attributes(task_params)
    if @task.errors.empty?
      redirect_to @task
    else
      render  'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @task.destroy
    redirect_to tasks_path
  end

  private

  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:title, :description, :priority, :status, :scheduled, :deadline, subtasks_attributes: [:title])
  end
  def find_task
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Show.html.erb for tasks/:id (just a rough draft)

```
<%= @task.deadline %>
<%= @task.title %>
<%= @task.description %>
<% @task.subtasks.each do |s| %>
  <br><%= s.title %>
  <%= link_to 'Delete', [s], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<% end %>

<%= simple_form_for @task do |t| %>
<%= t.simple_fields_for :subtasks do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :title %> 
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button  :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: 
We need one controller - TasksController.
We add parameter "accepts_nested_attributes_for" in model 'Task':

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many    :subtasks, class_name: 'Task', foreign_key: "parent_id"
  belongs_to  :parent, class_name: 'Task'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subtasks, allow_destroy: true
  belongs_to  :user
  belongs_to  :project
end
```

To TasksController we add additional parameters for subtasks:

```
def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit(:title, :description, :priority, :status, :scheduled, :deadline, subtasks_attributes: [:title])
end
```

Form for the subtasks looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @task do |t| %>
  <%= t.simple_fields_for :subtasks, @task.subtasks.build do |f| %>
    <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.input :title %> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button  :submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `accept_nested_attributes_for` for `subtasks`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

also consider using simple_form for passing nested model attributes

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models

with this approach, no need to create separate controller for subtasks

I think its good to use `subtasks` for one `parent` task

Comment: Oddly enough, the OP [already used nested attributes](http://i.imgur.com/dewIK8Y.png). Edited that out for some reason.

Comment: oh ok, but to achieve putting subtasks values in same form we need `accept nested attributes for`

Comment: Yep, i deleted it before and now returned. 
I have problems with controller and view for that.